# Imagens dos emojis do windows 10

Tags: windows, sistema-operacional, ícone

Desenvolvi uma aplicação que utiliza os ícones do Windows 10.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando rodo no Windows 11 além de ficar estranho com os ícones novos do sistema operacional, quebra algumas partes do layout.

Existe alguma forma de pegar as imagens reais dos ícones para publicar na minha aplicação para que isso não aconteça?

Answer (score -2):

Encontrei a fonte nas fontes do Windows.

Fonte no Windows Explorer:

```
"C:\Windows\Fonts\Segoe UI Emoji Regular"
```

Caminho real:

```
"C:\Windows\Fonts\seguiemj.ttf"
```

**Informações sobre licenciamento e redistribuição**

- [Perguntas frequentes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/font-faq) sobre redistribuição de fontes para Windows.
- [Licencie fontes da Microsoft](https://www.fonts.com/content/microsoft-typography) para empresas, desenvolvedores da web, para redistribuição de hardware e software ou instalações de servidor.

[**Fonte**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/segoe-ui-emoji)